# Little O Computation: $4n\:\in \:o\left(n^2\right)$

Tags: asymptotics

For this, I know you can use calculus techniques and set $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{4n}{n^2}\right)$ and get 0. Though, I'm wanting to know how you can get a specific constant and k values.

Comment: What is the definition of little o you use?

Comment: And what is $k$?

Comment: That limit is only 0 if n = 0. For any n > 0, it is 4/n > 0.

Comment: In other words, there is a typo - $x$ should be $n$ in the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want to use the limit, we can in this case use the definition (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for details):
$$
f(n)=o(g(n)) \stackrel{\text{def}}\equiv \forall k>0\,\exists N\ge 0\, \forall n\ge N\,[\:f(n)\le k\cdot g(n)\:]
$$
In other words, the definition is exactly the same as for big-O, except that the inequality eventually holds *for all* positive constant multiples $k$.

With this in mind, choose any positive $k$. Then to have 
$$
4n\le k\:n^2
$$
we need the equivalent
$$
\frac{4}{k}\le n
$$ 
so for any positive $k$ we'll have $4n\le n^2$ for all $n\ge N = 4/k$.